# iOS - Issue with Google Sign-In library

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

My iOS app used the Google+ library to perform the Google Account login, but that method has been deprecated and it's not working. So I want to use the new Google SignIn Library.

I have added the following to my pod file:

```
pod ‘Google/SignIn’
```

Then I have run the command 'pod install' to install it. The result:

```
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.9.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (3.6.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.10)
Installing FontAwesome (4.3.0)
Installing GTMOAuth2 (1.1.4)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.10)
Installing Google (3.0.3)
Installing GoogleSignIn (4.0.2)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
```

I have opened the project and, without changing any line of code, it fails to build with the following error:

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m:331:41: Use of undeclared identifier 'GTMOAuth2ErrorTokenUnavailable'; did you mean 'kGTMOAuth2ErrorTokenUnavailable'?
```

What is wrong with this library? It looks like it is using a variable that doesn't exist... GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m is a class from one of the new libraries installed with the Google SignIn library.

How can I use Google SignIn?

I'm following the official guide:https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

In that page there is not mention of that error.

My Xcode version is 7.3.1. It's an objective-c app.

Comment: I have done the same steps as mentioned above but Its working fine on my side.

Comment: @Himanshu Garg Could you explain the steps you have followed, please? Maybe you have done something different.

Comment: well I have done the same steps as yours. I can post  a video for the same if that could help.

Comment: Actually, it would help a great deal. Thanks!

Comment: same issue. what to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the video from following link:-

[Video Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/783gu4xsxgh5lfn/Sample.mov?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe I'm facing some kind of incompatibility with other libraries of the app...

Comment: @O.D. You can try one thing. Remove CocoaPods from your system completely and then re-install the same. May be there could be an issue with downloaded repository.

Comment: I gave up on Google SignIn. I could add it to any project except the one where I need it... Now I'm using AppAuth without no issue

Comment: Video link is expired buddy

Comment: My app is now using AppAuth for the Google Log-In: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS There you can find guides and examples.

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me when I have "googleplus-ios-sdk" pod library installed.
After removing the library, it works. "googleplus-ios-sdk" is an very outdated library (last update on 2014).

Perhaps you can create a new Xcode project, copy and install the pod libraries, and test one by one which library is having trouble with "GoogleSignIn".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try out of curiosity. Nowadays, my app doesn't use social networks to log in.